# Help jQuery plus prototype

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am getting the following error message:

```
When I called jQuery(...) with your args, an error was thrown!
TypeError: $("#contest-navigation ul li") is null
```

However, in the console, if I type:

```
jQuery("#contest-navigation ul li");
```

I am getting a not-null message (The only thing I see is "You've used the same selector more than once" which makes sense since it is an unordered list).

I think it's actually because I am using prototype (well, the person before me) with jQuery, but I am not sure how to resolve this. I do know when I take the link to the prototype library out that my jQuery code works correctly...

HTML:

```
<div id="contest-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a><span>About</span</a></li>
    <li><a><span>Enter</span</a></li>
    <li><a><span>Rules</span</a></li>
    <li><a><span>Prizes</span</a></li>
    <li><a><span>FAQ</span</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my complete code (tab-rollover.js):

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#contest-navigation ul li').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    jQuery('#contest-navigation ul li').click(function() {
        jQuery('#parents-subnav ul li').removeClass('selected');        
        jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
    });

});
```

Comment: please post the html containing `#contest-navigation`

Comment: Is this an analysis from some program?  jQuery.lint.js?  

I believe the same selector message means you've used $(selector) more than once, instead of storing it in a variable to cache it.

As far as both null and non-null returns... is the page loaded the first time you try to use the selector?  $(function(){ dowork(); });  
The page is obviously loaded when you do it manually in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your code is inside a [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) block.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that `$("#contest-navigation ul li")` is being called before it exists in the document.  Can you verify that it is happening after the document has loaded?